# FetchedResults not initialized before first use? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, initialization

kinda new to SwiftUI and CoreData.

My problem is that when CoreData already has data saved, the FetchedResults is not initialized when try to use data in sheet.

When I click on one of the buttons to open .viewApp sheet (which sets currentApplication to the application clicked on), it gives me the default values, implying that applications is not initialized.

After clicking another button, it works as expected.

My question is how can I initilize the FetchResults? Is it not initialized automatically?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    case newApp, viewApp
    
    var id: Int {
        hashValue
    }
}

struct ApplicationView : View {
    let title: String
    let company: String
    let date: String
    let notes: String
    
    var body : some View {
        Text(company)
        Text(title)
        Text(date)
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("Notes")
            Text(notes).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var applications:FetchedResults<Application>
    
    @State var showAddScreen = false
    @State var showApplicationView = false
    
    @State var currentApplication: Application? = nil

    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(applications.indices, id:\.self) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                        currentApplication = applications[i]
                        activeSheet = .viewApp
                    }, label: {
                        HStack{
                            VStack{
                                Text(applications[i].company ?? "Error")
                                Text(applications[i].title ?? "Error")
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Text(applications[i].date ?? "Error")
                        }
                    })
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteApplications)
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("Applications")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Add") {
                    activeSheet = .newApp
                }
            }
            
        }
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
            switch item {
            case .newApp:
                AddScreenView(moc: _moc, activeSheet: $activeSheet)
            case .viewApp:
                ApplicationView(title: currentApplication?.title ?? "Job Title", company: currentApplication?.company ?? "Company Name", date: currentApplication?.date ?? "Date of Submission", notes: currentApplication?.notes ?? "Notes")
            }
        }
    }
    func deleteApplications(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            let application = applications[offset]
            moc.delete(application)
        }
        try? moc.save()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I changed it to an if else in the ContentView and this has fixed the problem. However, it would be nice to know when the sheet is initialized prior to the fetchedreults.

Comment: If you want to use `currentApplication` inside that closure, you should include it in the `item`. You can also *try* adding `[currentApplication]` before `item in` to see if the capture solves it.

Comment: Unrelated but iterating over `applications.indices` and calling `applications[i]` four times is pretty inefficient.